# Translate Face of Cone in Maya while Vertex is Left Stationary (Programatically)

Tags: python, maya, translate, vertex

Is there an easy way of translating the face (and edges, consequently) of a polyCone in Maya, preferably using Python?  I can't even figure out how to select just the face of a cone without selecting the vertex as well, so translations move everything.

What I'd like to do is create a cone with the vertex at a certain point (x, y, z), then be able to move the face around without affecting the coordinates of the vertex.  Any ideas?

Comment: could you not move the base of the cone to a different set of coordinates?
What you're looking at, is trying to write a formula in python, than applying transformations. the formula for a cone is pi * r^2(h/3) where r is the radius and h is the height. Or, you can hardcode the vertex and make other points of the cone dynamic?

Comment: @awbemauler I can hardcorde the vertex but I can't figure out how to select the face without selecting the whole cone.  All selection tools I've tried select the whole cone.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting or moving the faces of of the cone involves adding the right face indices. So:

```
# whole object
cmds.select('pCone1')

# some only faces #0 and #1
cmds.select('pCone1.f[0]', 'pCone1.f[1]')

# select all faces, without moving the pCone1 transform:
cmds.select('pCone1.f[*]')
```

to move the faces, use the same syntax with the `move` or `xform` commands:

```
# move face[0] down by 1 unit in world space
cmds.xform('pCone1.f[0]', t= (0,-1, 0), r=True, ws=True)
```

the trick will be figuring out which faces form the base of the cone. If you create the cone with the `polyCone` command, face 0 will always be the base; if the cone is modelled some other way you'll probably want to ask the user to select it for you.